# Swift function tag confusion

Tags: swift, function, tags

Same function code in different file, but called in different way

in the AppDelegate.swift i wrote:

```
func findIndexOfString(str: String, arr: [String]) -> Int?{
    for (index, value) in enumerate(arr){
        if (value == str){
                return index
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

i can call this function like this way, no problem: (of course in AppDeleagte class)

```
let index = findIndexOfString(name, arr: neighbors)
```

then i move the WHOLE function code to another file--Function.swift(not in a class), i must call the function like this way:

```
let index = findIndexOfString(name, neighbors) // no arr:
```

why? Maybe swift treat the functions not in a class as a global scope C function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you move the WHOLE function code to another file--Function.swift(not in a class) then You can call that function like `let index = findIndexOfString(name, neighbors)` because you define it outside of the class that means it is a global function and you can access it anywhere.

Unless you declare the function as private, which limits the visibility to the file where it is defined, you can use it anywhere in the module if declared as internal (the default), and also from external modules if declared as public.

For more Information about functions you can refer [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html).

**UPDATE:**

The fact that structures and enumerations can define methods in Swift is a major difference from C and Objective-C. In Objective-C, classes are the only types that can define methods. In Swift, you can choose whether to define a class, structure, or enumeration, and still have the flexibility to define methods on the type you create.

Local and External Parameter Names for Methods:

Methods in Swift are very similar to their counterparts in Objective-C.

Swift gives the first parameter name in a method a local parameter name by default, and gives the second and subsequent parameter names both local and external parameter names by default. This convention matches the typical naming and calling convention you will be familiar with from writing Objective-C methods, and makes for expressive method calls without the need to qualify your parameter names.

Consider this `Counter` class, which defines a more complex form of the `incrementBy(_:)` method:

```
class Counter {
    var count: Int = 0
    func incrementBy(amount: Int, numberOfTimes: Int) {
        count += amount * numberOfTimes
    }
}
```

This `incrementBy(_:numberOfTimes:)` method has two parameters—amount and `numberOfTimes`. By default, Swift treats amount as a local name only, but treats `numberOfTimes` as both a local and an external name. You call the method as follows:

```
let counter = Counter()
counter.incrementBy(5, numberOfTimes: 3)
// counter value is now 15
```

You don’t need to define an external parameter name for the first argument value, because its purpose is clear from the function name incrementBy(_:numberOfTimes:). The second argument, however, is qualified by an external parameter name to make its purpose clear when the method is called.

The behaviour described above means that method definitions in Swift are written with the same grammatical style as Objective-C, and are called in a natural, expressive way.

For more info refer this [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-ID234).

And you can check [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYpLPBfkhnY) video and you will get your answer at 0:55.

Comment: actually, my question is why i moved my code in another file, the way i call the function changed (without a tag--arr:)?

Comment: hi, i guess i found another explanation about my question... http://www.objc.io/issues/16-swift/swift-functions/ (Calling All Functions and Calling on Methods). This article said if the code not included by a class will be treat as a FUNCTION, if it is, i will be treat as a METHOD. The way we call function and method is different..

Comment: I already provided a link of docs in my answer you can check there.